# eclipse debugger: break on specific method call by specific object

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Using the debugger, I want to break when a particular method is called on a particular object.  For example, if I have 2 HashMaps (`m1`, `m2`), I want to break every time I call `m1.put()`, but NOT when I call `m2.put()`.

I do have access to the source of the method call I am breaking on, but if I put the breakpoint on entry to the `put()` method, it will break on every instance, not just the one I want.  Is what I want possible without setting individual breakpoints at every line that calls the method?

Answer (score 0):

You can set conditional breakpoints in eclipse, meaning you can give a breakpoint a condition when to "break", or go into stepping mode.

To do this, right-click the breakpoint and select "Breakpoint Properties".

So now you need a distinction between you two instances that you can turn into a code statement, which i can't provide you since I don't know your code...

Comment: is it possible some other way? My code is massive (10s of millions of lines) and there are dozens of instances of the class.  I'm not sure I can create a condition that will break on one particular instance and not another.  particularly if we're dealing with collections (we are) that don't really have any fields other than their contents.